# Open subsequent windows in Tkinter

Tags: javascript, python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I would like my code to open a new window using `Tkinter` after the user inputs a string into the `Entry` box.

```
#First Window, Start or Information
def start():
    q1 = tkinter.Tk()
    q1.title("Sports")
    q1.geometry("500x170")
    q1.configure(bg='#00BFFF')
    event1 = tkinter.Label(q1, text="What Sports Event Did You Participate In? \n 1) Football \n 2) Hockey \n 3) Basketball \n 4) Badminton \n 5) Rounders", fg="#383A39", bg="#00BFFF", font=("Helvetica", 15))
    event1.pack()
    ans = tkinter.Entry(q1, width=80)
    ans.pack()
    def qu1():
        deranswer = ans.get()
        if deranswer == "football" or deranswer == "Football" or deranswer == "1":
            crr = tkinter.Label(q1, text="Thank You!", fg="green")
            crr.pack()
            team = tkinter.Tk()
            team.title("Team/Individual?")
            team.geometry("500x500")
            team.configure(bg='#00BFFF')
            event2 = tkinter.Label(team, text="Would You Like To Enter As A Team or Individual?", fg="#383A39", bg="#00BFFF")
            event2.pack()
            ans2 = tkinter.Entry(team, width=80)
            ans2.pack()
            def qu2():
                deranswer = ans2.get()
                if deranswer == "Team" or deranswer == "1":
                    total_score = 0
                    wins = 0
                    losses = 0
                    draws = 0
                    q3 = tkinter.Tk()
                    q3.title("Team Score")
                    q3 = tkinter.Label(window, text="Please Enter Your Team Name", fg="#383A39", bg="#00BFFFF")
                    ans3 = tkinter.Entry(q3, width=80)
                    ans3.pack()
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: And there are no errors in the console?

Comment: No, none. I just type football and nothing works..

Comment: Sorry. It took me a while to write my answer. You will find some more information that may help you in my answer. ;-)

Comment: its okay, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*At first a little hint: Especially when you are a beginner, please pass the complete code. The problem could be anywhere from a failing main loop to a bad event handler.*

I see no line where you bound qu1() to a Button click or an Enter keypress in the Entry field. qu1() simply never gets executed.

You could add a button like this: `Button(q1, text='Submit',command=qu1).pack()` to create a button or `ans.bind('<Key-Return>', qu1)` to bind the enter key event for the entry. But then you would have to replace `def qu1()` with `def qu1(event=None)` since a click event information may be send to the functiom qu1.

Also please do not use nested `def` s. It's a bad style. You could create them all in the main code. Otherwise I would suggest you reading about python classes.

Last but no least my advice is to take a look at tkinter messageboxes. For you purpose they let you ask the user much easier and even more "beautiful" than in your example code. (if we can call those windows beautiful).

Comment: Please stop using `TkinterWidget.pack()` in the same line as defining it, it's really poor code.

Comment: Yes. It poor for proper windows. However Leeeaaann seems to create simple popup windows. I used the one-liner because more lines would obfuscate the code **even** more than it is already. Of course I am aware that you are right.

Answer (score 0):

You never call the next function to work. After you have the user input their desired sport, function `qu1` is not called, so no additional code is made to run. You can rectify this by creating a button which runs the next section of code. For example:

```
ans = tkinter.Entry(q1, width=80)
confirm = tkinter.Button(q1, width=10, text="Confirm", command=lambda: qu1())
ans.pack()
confirm.pack()
```

When the user has inputted, they then have to click the confirm button for the next sub routine to run.

Good Luck!

Comment: Oh, thank you so much, 5 days left on an assignment and 'm rushing lol. Thanks for the help

Comment: green tick under the 0?

Comment: is there any way to private message?